# What does $d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ in integral mean?

Tags: lebesgue-integral

What does $d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ under integral sign mean?
Like $$\int_B Xd\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}(\omega)$$

Can somebody explain? How can we integrate $X$ with respect to  $\mathbb{P}(\omega)$ where $\mathbb{P}$ is some prob. measure?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration

$X$ is an r.v. and as a function it is a measurable function with respect to the Probability measure.

Comment: This has been asked before. See the answers [here] (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916776/what-does-mathbbpd-omega-dw-actually-mean)

Comment: See also this post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/5230/notation-question-integrating-against-a-measure

Comment: **How can we integrate X with respect to ℙ(ω) where ℙ is some prob. measure?**  Perhaps first you should find out how we can integrate a function $f$ with respect to a measure $\mu$, that is $\int f\;d\mu$.  Then simply replace $f$ and $\mu$ by $X$ and $\mathbb P$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula in your post is ill-formed. One can use one of the equivalent $$\int_B X(\omega)d\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}(\omega),\qquad\int_B Xd\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}.$$ One also finds the alternative $$\int_B X(\omega)\mathbb{\mathbb{P}}(d\omega).$$

Comment: Isnt that better as a comment?

Comment: @Snufsan Is it?

Comment: Wouldn't this be improved by including the definition and perhaps a link, e.g. to [Lebesgue integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration)?

Comment: @Did actually, it is

Comment: @Snufsan I'm inclined to agree, but if OP is confused by the presence of the $\omega$ rather than by integrating with respect to a measure, then Did's answer is appropriate.  I guess it depends on how you read the original question.

Answer (score 5):

A probability measure can be looked at as a function $\mathbb{P}:\mathcal{A}\rightarrow\left[0,1\right]$
where $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra. The function has some
nice properties like $\mathbb{P}\left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\right)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}\left(A_{n}\right)$
when the $A_{n}$ are disjoint elements of $\mathcal{A}$. There is
a one to one correspondence beween elements of $\mathcal{A}$ and
their characteristic functions $1_{A}$ so equally well we could look
at $\mathbb{P}$ as a function on characteristic functions. This opens
the door to expanding the domain of $\mathbb{P}$. We can make it a function on
so-called $\mathcal{A}$-measurable functions, that takes values in
$\mathbb{R}$. Again it has nice properties. If $X$ is such
a measurable function then $\mathbb{P}\left(X\right)$ could be practicized as a notation of its value under $\mathbb{P}$. However, the notation $\mathbb{P}\left(X\right)$
is (mostly) not practicized, and $\mathbb P$ is not looked at as a function on functions ([why not](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/879527/75923)?). Instead one uses notations like $\int Xd\mathbb{P}$
, $\int X\left(\omega\right)d\mathbb{P}\left(\omega\right)$ or $\int X\left(\omega\right)\mathbb{P}\left(d\omega\right)$, and speaks of integrals. Here $\int_{B}Xd\mathbb{P}$ is
a notation for $\int X.1_{B}d\mathbb{P}$.