# What is the differential probability notation used in this paper by Einstein?

Tags: probability-distributions, notation

Earlier today, I saw a discussion on Einstein's 1917 paper [On The Quantum Theory of Radiation](http://www.timeisabsolute.org/einsteinlaser.pdf). Section 2 of the paper introduces three equations that I'm neither sure how they are derived nor what they're supposed to represent.

For instance, section 2 defines the following equation (the other two are similar, but introduce $\rho$, a radiation density):

$$dW = A_m^ndt$$

$A_m^n$ is a constant, and $dt$ is a "very small" unit of time. On the other hand, $dW$ is said to be a *probability* that emission of radiation occurs during $dt$.

My first confusion is that the probability is represented using a differential $dW$. Earlier in the paper the same variable $W$ is also used to represent a density function. However, setting aside that confusion for a moment, since $A_m^n$ is a constant, and $t$ is presumably unbounded:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}A_m^ndt = \infty$$

The above should equal 1 for $dW$ to represent a distribution.

This makes me think I'm either missing some implicit assumptions, and/or Einstein is not calculating a traditional integral using Riemann sums.

According to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916776/what-does-mathbbpd-omega-dw-actually-mean), taking the differential of a probability density function occurs in stochastic calculus. Considering we are dealing with molecules in a gas, this makes sense.

So is the above equation an example of describing a stochastic process? If so, is there a less-terse way in writing the equation that would also show more clearly that this is not an integral calculated using Riemann sums? If so, I do not have the background to understand this paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Radiation from a material (neglecting the overall decrease in radioactive atoms) is a stochastic process in which in a given time interval every atom has a certain chance of decaying. If the time interval $\Delta t$ is short enough then there is a very small probability of having 1 decay and an extremely small of having two or more decays. Einsteins $dW$ denotes this probability of having 1 decay (and thus neglects the possibility of two or more). 
From temporal invariance it must be proportional to the length of
the time interval: $dW = a \; dt$. This only makes sense when $dW$ is small compared to 1.

Another way to think of it is as the average number of decays in the interval $dt$. Chopping a (not so small) time interval $[0,T]$ into $n$ tiny intervals where Einsteins argument works allow you to show that e.g. $X$, the total number of decays is a random variable following a Poisson distribution: If  $\Delta t=T/n$ is small enough so that we can neglect multiple decays in each interval, then $p=a \Delta t=aT/n$ is the (approx) probability of one decay in each interval, and these decays may be assumed independent. Having $k$ decays in total is (approx) a binomial distribution (let $n\rightarrow \infty$ for fixed $k$):
$$ P(X=k)=\left( \begin{matrix} n\\k \end{matrix} \right) \left(\frac{aT}{n}\right)^k \left(1- \frac{aT}{n}\right)^{n-k} \rightarrow \frac{1}{k!} (aT)^k e^{-aT}$$

You may also derive an ODE for the probability of having no decays up to a certain time. Your integral (over some fixed 'long' period of time) represents the average total number of decays in that period. It may  not be interpreted as a probability anymore.

Comment: Okay, accepting this answer, with two follow ups:
1. As $\Delta t$ approaches zero, can it be proven that at most one decay will occur? This makes sense to me intuitively, but I'm not sure how to prove it.
2. Wouldn't the expected value require me to take the following integral:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}tA_{m}^{n}dt$$

Comment: As $\Delta t$ goes to zero the probablity of having any (including one) decay goes to zero. What is important is that the ratio of the expected number of decays (which is $a \; dt$) and having one decay (which is $a e^{-a \; dt}$, from the above distribution) goes to one! This is the essential point which allows you to think of this 'expected' value as a probability. The expected value is given by $\sum_k P(X=k)$ from the above distribution and this equals precisely $a \; dt$. [Remember you only look at the (tiny) time interval $dt$]