# Meaning of P(dw)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I'm reading Shreve's *Stochastic Calculus for Finance*.

On page 35, he gives this example:

> Example 1.6.4.
>
> Recall Example 1.2.4 in which $\Omega =  [0, 1]$, $\mathbb{P}$ is the
> uniform (i.e., Lebesgue) measure, and
>
> $$\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}[a, b] = \int_a^b 2\omega d\omega = b^2 - a^2,
> > 0 \leq a \leq b \leq 1.$$
>
> We may use the fact that $\mathbb{P}(d\omega)=d\omega$ to rewrite the
> above as
>
> $$\widetilde{\mathbb{P}}[a, b] = \int_{[a, b]} 2\omega d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$$

I'm confused by "$\mathbb{P}(d\omega)=d\omega$". In my mind, $\mathbb{P}$ is a measure, $d\omega$ outside of an integral is meaningless, and $\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$ symbolically doesn't have any meaning.

How do I interpret $\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$? How do I make sense of Shreve's substitution?

Edit: What set is the equivalence relation $=$ in "$\mathbb{P}(d\omega)=d\omega$" defined over?

Comment: I just saw that there is an identical question here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/916776/what-does-mathbbpd-omega-dw-actually-mean?rq=1

I am hesitant to delete since this question now has an answer.

Comment: Since I can't figure out how to close, I have just flagged the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\mathbb{P}(d\omega)$ means $d\mathbb{P}(\omega)$. It's just another notation. Since $\mathbb{P}$ is the Lebesgue measure here, we have $d\mathbb{P}(\omega) = d\omega$.

Comment: $d\omega$ does not mean anything to me outside of an integral. I don't know what set the binary relation $=$ you use in your comment is defined over.

Comment: Are you somewhat familiar with measures?

Comment: Yes, I am familiar with measures. I am not familiar with interpreting "$d\omega$" as a measure. Am I to interpret it as the Lebesgue measure? Is it just stating an equality of measures? If so, I guess I was just confused because "$P(dω)$" really doesn't *look* like a measure.

Comment: If for example $\mu$ is absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue measure, people often write $d\mu = f\,dx$. It makes sense because then$$\int_Af\,d\mu = \int_A\frac{d\mu}{dx}\,dx = \int_A\,d\mu = \mu(A),$$which holds by Rado-Nikodym. Here, we have $d\mathbb P = 1\,dx$.